# Unity - How to create a Custom Editor for dynamically change size of a list inside an other list with custom size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want to create a Custom Editor for Unity with a list inside a list and allow to edit the size dynamically and with a Popup inside the second list.

Here is a couple of examples of what I want:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

The problem is that I can't change the second list size because it change the size of all the elements in the second list, so i can't have diferent sizes for each element of list.

Also I have the same problem with the popup, the item selected is allways the same for all the popups (as you can see in the second image).

How I can save each dimension or popup selected of each item selected without changing the others?

Here is my code:

> ScriptableObject class

```
public class MyClass : ScriptableObject {

public class MyInsideClass
{
    public List<string> data;

    public MyInsideClass()
    {
        data = new List<string>();
    }
}

public List<MyInsideClass> allData;
}
```

> Custom Editor (Database just have the popup list names)

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyClass))]
public class TempEdior : Editor
{
    int numberOfCombinations = 0;
    int numberOfDataForCombination = 0;
    int selected = 0;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Number of combinations:");
        numberOfCombinations =         EditorGUILayout.IntField(numberOfCombinations);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCombinations; i++)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.Label("Combination " + (i + 1) + " - number of data:");
            numberOfDataForCombination =     EditorGUILayout.IntField(numberOfDataForCombination);
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfDataForCombination; j++)
            {
                Rect rect = EditorGUILayout.GetControlRect();
                selected = EditorGUI.Popup(new Rect(rect.x + 63, rect.y, 100, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), selected,     Database.Instance.slotTypes.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Looks at the requirements* Eugh. I have no desire to write that custom inspector script at all. The important thing to remember though: whatever data your inspector is displaying must be in the object you have edited. You can't "store" data in the inspector script itself.

Comment: Yes, I know i've to write another part of code for saving all the data in the scriptable object and creating or removing new element of the list size would be saved in the scriptablrObject. But this is just the part of the editor to make the text simpler, I know how to store the target object or the serializedObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you're approaching this the wrong way. It's easy to get carried away writing inspector code forever, in convoluted ways that break Unity's paradigms for little benefit. Rely on SerializedProperties as much as you can, as it will handle undo, multi-edit etc.

Basically all you want is to edit a string using a popup, right? Then just use a PropertyDrawer for this, and for the rest just let Unity's array inspector do its magic:
[image]

```cs
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestArrayOfArray : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct ComboItem
    {
        public string value;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct Combo
    {
        public ComboItem[] items;
    }

    public Combo[] combos;
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(TestArrayOfArray.ComboItem))]
public class ComboItemDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    static readonly string[] comboItemDatabase = { "Bla", "Bli", "Blu" };
    static readonly GUIContent[] comboItemDatabaseGUIContents = Array.ConvertAll(comboItemDatabase, i => new GUIContent(i));

    public override void OnGUI( Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label )
    {
        property = property.FindPropertyRelative("value");

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        int selectedIndex = Array.IndexOf(comboItemDatabase, property.stringValue);
        selectedIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(position, label, selectedIndex, comboItemDatabaseGUIContents);
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            property.stringValue = comboItemDatabase[selectedIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

This is very crude, runtime + inspector code in a single file, fake "database" hard-coded as a static array, doesn't handle mixed values in case of a multi-edit, etc etc, but it should get you started.

--

General advice: favor arrays over Lists if you can, eg in this case the combos are static serialized data that you're never gonna resize at runtime, so an array is more efficient.

Inline field declarations when possible for readability (eg `public List<string> data = new List<string>();` is fine).

Don't initialize arrays/lists that are serialized, as their default value will be overwritten by deserialization, leading to a wasted allocation.

Comment: It's a very nice aproach but not working because I need to use a ScriptableObjectand and not a MonoBehaviour. However this answer help me to realize I was in the wrong way and SerializedProperties are better for my purpose. Now is working using some tips of your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Wyrncael using a `ScriptableObject` changes nothing, this approach will work just as well... try it :) .
That's the beauty of `PropertyDrawers`, they target any struct/class anywhere, instead of replacing the whole inspector of a given `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: I tried with your code but only work if I use `Monobehaviour` instead of `ScriptableObject`. I don't know why I can't use `CustomPropertyDrawer` in `ScriptableObject`. Maybe I put something more wrong but using your code in my `CustomEditor` without an specific `CustomPropertyDrawer` and using `SerializedProperties` works fine. Thanks again!